# ShellExecute and notifying the event of closing the launched file in c program

Tags: shellexecute

I have opened a .doc file in internet explorer using ShellExecute() in a c program.Is there any way that program which has called ShellExecute() gets notified when the opened file in the explorer is closed?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is now way to achieve this. `ShellExecute` does not provide a way to wait for the program it invokes to execute.

Indeed, there may not even be a program to execute: imagine trying to `open`, say, a .PDF file on a system that doesn't have Adobe Reader or Acrobat or any other such software installed.

All you get is success or failure in response to the shell attempting to find and execute the action in the registry that is associated with the file and verb you passed in.